# Magento: In Category why does setName not work

Tags: php, magento

I have two questions about Magento category naming.

1. as I have to change the name of bunch of categories, I have written this:

   ```
   $category = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' );
   $tree = $category->getTreeModel ();
   $tree->load ();

   $ids = $tree->getCollection ()->getAllIds ();

   if ($ids) {
          foreach ( $ids as $id ) 
             if ($change[$id] != "") {
                   $_category->setName($change[$id]);
                   $_category->save();
           }
   }
   ```

   But this does not save the name of the categories?
2. Can I change the name of the "Default Category"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>TheVyom provided this answer in his own question:</sup>

As I was not in the ADMIN Store, the changes being made the the categeory was not being reflected. To fix this, I needed to add

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```